# Automatic call recorder restore files

Tags: applications

When updating the app all files (saved) disappeared from the app.

Is there a way to restore them on the app.
I wanted to export them as backup but it seem impossible.
My phone is not rooted so I can't have access to them. (Can't see them)
Thanks

Comment: Which app are you talking about? Please edit your question and name the app including a link to it's Play Store Web site.

Comment: It's in the title. Automatic call recorder. I'm trying to retrieve the recorded messages. Thanks

Comment: There are multiple apps with that name.  To allow people to help you, please provide an F-Droid or Google Play store link to that app within your question.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.q4u.autocallrecorder

Comment: The recordings must be there as I have 956mb of data and the app is only 34mb. But File manager won't give give authorisation to access to them.